# Usar namespace em include

Tags: php, namespace

Estou usando namespace para utilizar classes no PHP, tem uma parte onde faço

`use StatusCorrida\StatusCorrida;
include('arquivo.php');`

O `arquivo.php` faz

```
$var = new StatusCorrida();
```

esse arquivo faz uso dessas classe `StatusCorrida`, porém o arquivo não reconhece o `namespace` declarado fora do arquivo.
O erro que diz é que a class StatusCorrida não foi encontrada.

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro ?

Comment: Que não encontra a Classe StatusCorrida

Comment: O `arquivo.php` onde você está incluíndo outro `namespace` possui um namespace também? Essa pergunta é importate! Se puder, posta um trecho do código pra ficar mais fácil entedermos.

Comment: edite a questão com mais informações. Está muito vago.

Answer (score 0):

Os namespaces são definidos em cada ficheiro, pois por defeito o namespace do ficheiro é `\`, sendo assim, no topo do ficheiro `arquivo.php` precisas incluir o namespace da classes que queres usar `use StatusCorrida\StatusCorrida;`